# Kernel of a linear map over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $d:\mathbb{Q}^{2}\to\mathbb{Q}^{2}$ be the linear map given by
$$d=\begin{pmatrix} 5 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

I would like to know what is the kernel. Now,

$$\ker d=\text{span{$a$}}\cong \mathbb{Q}$$

for $a\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: what is $a$ in the proposed solution?

Answer (score 2):

$$\ker(d)=\operatorname{span}\begin{pmatrix}1\\-5\end{pmatrix}=\left\{a(i-5j):a\in\Bbb Q,i=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix},j=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}\right\}\cong \Bbb Q$$
where $\ker(d)\cong\Bbb Q$ via $a(i-5j)\mapsto a$.